# Двоичное число записано в массиве нужно к нему прибавить 1

Tags: java, массивы

Есть число в двоичной системе счисления записанное в одномерном массиве к нему нужно прибавить единицу. Снизу привел свой код, но он выводит тоже самое число.
P.s работа с 5пятизначными числами в 10 системе счисления.

```
int vyme=1;
    for (int k =17;k>=0;k--) {
                    if ((num[k]+vyme)==2) {
                        vyme=1;
                        num[k]=0;
                    }
                    if ((num[k]+vyme)==1) {
                        vyme=0;
                        num[k]=1;
                    }
                    if ((num[k]+vyme)==0) {
                        vyme=0;
                        num[k]=0;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int k =17;k>-1;k--) {
            if ((num[k]+vyme)==2) {
                num[k]=0;
                vyme=1;

            }
            else if ((num[k]+vyme)==1) {                 
                vyme=0;
                num[k]=1;
            }
            else if ((num[k]+vyme)==0) {
                vyme=0;
                num[k]=0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: В настоящем виде не является ответом. Вот если бы был пример как именно использовать, то совсем другое дело.